# How to check if Google Doc is loaded inside an iframe or not

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want the users to work on Google documents only inside my application (where the documents will be loaded inside an iframe). If they attempt to open the document using Google Doc independent from the application, they should see an error message and the document should not be displayed.

I wonder if there is a way to do this. Google apps scripts would work this task or not?

Comment: @TheMaster thanks! I am doing it like this: `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />` and it works fine.

Comment: Is  the document public? Is that a standard browser? I don't see how you bypassed CSP/XFRAME options.

Comment: @TheMaster sorry for missing information. Yes, the document will be public. They will need to click on a link to be able to load it inside my application.

Comment: If it's public, then it's almost always accessible. But, you can try loading a modal dialog/sidebar and try  something like `window.parent.location === window.top.location`(may or may not work). parent because modal dialog itself will be loaded in a iframe. Structure: Your site>googledoc frame>modal dialog frame

Comment: @TheMaster so I do this check `window.parent.location === window.top.location` with google apps script?

Comment: Google apps script running server side --> loads client side html --> sidebar/modal dialog in browser. You'll check it in client side JavaScript.